# How to define route in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have a blog website using Nuxt.Js suppose xyz.com and want to display all pages country code specific like xyz.com/en/home, xyz.com/en/about etc.

How to define route in nuxt.js, the purpose is display blog all country wise , it's not multi language website only doing for display data country specific

Comment: You can use nuxt-i18n: https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/

Comment: I have to display record country specific and URL should be fine like xyz.com/np/category/test-category and dont want to place any language file an d no need to change language all record should be English

Answer (score 0):

Make a directory starting with underscore saying _lang and put your pages there.

- pages

  - _lang

    - Home.vue
    - About.vue

Then use [page validation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-validate/) to only accept [country codes](https://gist.github.com/vxnick/380904)

```
const country_codes = [ 'en', 'fa']
export default {
  validate({ params }) {
    return (params.lang in country_codes)
  }
}
```